# when reading a file, does the order of size and count really matter?

Tags: c, io

In C, what is the difference between these two?

```
fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
fread(buffer, 1, fileLen, file);
```

Both reads the file into an array, and `fileLen * 1 == 1 * fileLen`, as we all know.